# How does generator * / splat unpacking work?

Tags: python, generator, expansion, splat

Let's say I have some function `f` that will accept a variable number of arguments:

```py
def f(*args):
    for a in args:
        print(a)
```

Below I call on this function three ways:

###### Case 1: Passing in a generator expression *without* parenthesis:

```py
f(l for l in range(5))
>>> <generator object <genexpr> at 0x1234>
```

###### Case 2: Passing in a generator expression *with* parenthesis:

```py
f((l for l in range(5)))
>>> <generator object <genexpr> at 0x1234>
```

###### Case 3: Passing in a generator expression *with* parenthesis and then expanding it with `*` aka splat:

```py
f(*(l for l in range(5)))
>>> 0
>>> 1
>>> 2
>>> 3
>>> 4
```

#### Here are my questions:

1. Testing for equality, `f(l for l in range(5)) == f((l for l in range(5)))` returns:

   ```py
   <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f8b2a5df570>
   <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f8b2a5df570>
   True
   ```

   This indicates to me that the parenthesis around the generator expression don't actually do anything.  Is that correct?
2. What is happening in case 1 and 2? When called individually, the output indicates that it created a generator. Further, when tested for equality in question 2 above, while I would have expected a simple `True`/`False` output, it couldn't help itself and showed me that it created a generator object for each of the function calls(?).  That said, if I assign the output to a new variable, i.e. `f2 = f(l for l in range(5))`, `f2` is `NoneType` and `f2.__next__()` throws an error (`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not an iterator`), indicating to me that the generator I just created can't be assigned to a variable.
3. Are the parenthesis in case 3 simply there to package up my expression so that it can be `*` expanded? Put another way, are the parenthesis only there because `*l for l in range(5)` can't be understood by the interpreter?
4. In case 3, what is the order of operations?
5. Continuing from the previous question - in case 3, what does `f()` "see"?
6. What is the correct verbiage to describe case 3? "Expanding a generator and passing it into a function"? Is any of my phraseology above incorrect?

##### Context:

Should it help, I'm reading [this Real Python tutorial on `asyncio`](https://realpython.com/async-io-python/#the-rules-of-async-io), in which they repeatedly use generator expansions(?) like:

```py
async def main():
    res = await asyncio.gather(*(makerandom(i, 10 - i - 1) for i in range(3)))
    return res
```

...which I *gather* is equal to:

```py
async def main():
    res = await asyncio.gather(makerandom(0, 9),makerandom(1, 8), makerandom(2, 7))
    return res
```

...but this is the first time in my Python career that I've really confronted *The Generator Arts*.

Comment: 1. Is that correct? Yes. 2: `f` doesn't _return_ anything, so you're comparing `None == None`. `That said, if I assign the output to a new variable` Again, assigning None. `it couldn't help itself and showed me that it created a generator object for each of the function calls(?)` You literally print the argument inside the function, so why are you surprised that it actually prints the generator object?

Comment: `f` doesn't have a `return` statement, so it implicitly returns `None`.  i.e. the return value is useless.  Cases 1 and 2 are the same.  You can only omit the generator parentheses if it's the sole argument to a function.  Case 3 expands the generator into a `tuple`, which is the value of `args` in `f`.

Comment: @tkausl In my confusion I forgot that those prints were coming from `f` itself. I rather thought that `f` wasn't running and was instead just creating a generator (the same as if i just did `(l for l in range(5))`). Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This indicates to me that the parenthesis around the generator expression don't actually do anything. Is that correct?

You’re correct that the parentheses don’t do anything, but the `==` test doesn’t show that; `f` always returns `None`, so `f(a) == f(b)` for any two values `a` and `b` (that allow `f` to return).

> Further, when tested for equality in question 2 above, while I would have expected a simple True/False output, it couldn't help itself and showed me that it created a generator object for each of the function calls(?).

`(l for l in range(5))` is an expression that creates a generator object. `f` prints the generator object when you call it because the generator object is an element of `args` and you told it to print every element of `args`. If you  tried `f(1) == f(2)` it would print 1 and 2.

> Are the parenthesis in case 3 simply there to package up my expression so that it can be `*` expanded? Put another way, are the parenthesis only there because `*l for l in range(5)` can't be understood by the interpreter?

Yes.

> In case 3, what is the order of operations?

- `(l for l in range(5))` evaluates to a generator expression
- `f(*value)` iterates over `value` and converts it to an argument list, calling `f` with that argument list

> Continuing from the previous question - in case 3, what does `f()` "see"?

`args == (1, 2, 3, 4)`. You can `print(args)` to see this; it’s just a tuple.

> What is the correct verbiage to describe case 3? "Expanding a generator and passing it into a function"?

Sure.